# python-simple string tokenizer using nltk

Tags: nltk

I want to take a string as text and make a tokenizer that will split it into words
I want my tokenizer to be able to identify email accounts, URLs, numbers and punctuation symbols.

I used regular expressions and I was able to create the patterns to recognize each of the preious categories. I just cant figure out how to split into tokens the words that dont follow any of these patterns
for example

```
patternpunctuation="[^\w\s]\s+"
patternnumber="[0-9]+"
patternmail="\w+@{1}[^\s<>()@]+"
patternurl="https?://[^\s<>()\"]+|www\.[^\s<>\"]+"
```

The string I want to tokenize is

```
line=" John 32 Smith global@hotmail.com.gr ddfdwww.google.com        fdfdhttp://google.com/index/agroup.html peter murphy alexis xronis 54^ & ^ & ^ & % % $ % % ^ ^ ! 68! @ @ # https://facebook.com.edu  re@dfdffe.gov.gr ! @ ^ "
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: I want it to be something like 
'John' '32' 'Smith' 'global@hotmail.com.gr' 'ddfd' 'www.google.com'        'fdfd' 'http://google.com/index/agroup.html' 'peter' 'murphy' 'alexis' 'xronis' '54' '^' '&' '^' '&' '^' '&' '%'  etc

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you don't want to use `word_tokenze` because it's getting all the emails wrong:

```
>>> line=" John 32 Smith global@hotmail.com.gr ddfdwww.google.com        fdfdhttp://google.com/index/agroup.html peter murphy alexis xronis 54^ & ^ & ^ & % % $ % % ^ ^ ! 68! @ @ # https://facebook.com.edu  re@dfdffe.gov.gr ! @ ^ "
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> word_tokenize(line)
['John', '32', 'Smith', 'global', '@', 'hotmail.com.gr', 'ddfdwww.google.com', 'fdfdhttp', ':', '//google.com/index/agroup.html', 'peter', 'murphy', 'alexis', 'xronis', '54^', '&', '^', '&', '^', '&', '%', '%', '$', '%', '%', '^', '^', '!', '68', '!', '@', '@', '#', 'https', ':', '//facebook.com.edu', 're', '@', 'dfdffe.gov.gr', '!', '@', '^']
```

If they are all separated by spaces, then you're looking for can be achieved simply with `str.split()`:

```
['John', '32', 'Smith', 'global@hotmail.com.gr', 'ddfdwww.google.com', 'fdfdhttp://google.com/index/agroup.html', 'peter', 'murphy', 'alexis', 'xronis', '54^', '&', '^', '&', '^', '&', '%', '%', '$', '%', '%', '^', '^', '!', '68!', '@', '@', '#', 'https://facebook.com.edu', 're@dfdffe.gov.gr', '!', '@', '^']
```

But to identify words joint together is not an easy task...

You can try the following tricks to fish out the `http`, `www` and `e@mail.whatever` but please note that you will SURELY need to modify the regex to suit your data.

```
re.findall(r'www\.[a-z].*.com', i) # www
re.findall(r'http:[a-z\/].*.html', i) # http
re.findall(r'https:[a-z\/].*', i) # https
re.findall(r'[a-z].*@[a-z].*.gov.[a-z].*',  # xxx@xxx.gov.xxx
```

Comment: it took me quite a long time but i finally found the following patterns

patternpunctuation="\\.\\.\\.|[^\w\s@]"
patternnumber=re.compile("[0-9]+\\.*,*[0-9]+")
patternmail=re.compile("\w+@{1}[^\s<>()@]+")
patternurl=re.compile("https?://[^\s<>()\"]+|www\.[^\s<>\"]+")
patternword=re.compile("[A-Za-z]+")

i combine them in one pattern and it seem to work pretty good.
Thank you very much for your answer alvas